# Android Studio static analysis from gradle / command line

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, static-analysis

I understand that Analyze->Inspect code within Android Studio actually executes two distinct tools: Android Lint and the inbuilt IntelliJ static analysis.

My dev team would like to avoid committing code with IntelliJ errors.  Because these don't fail the build, they are too easy to miss.

How can I integrate the IntelliJ analysis into my build.gradle file so that any errors will fail the build.  I already integrated Android Lint, Checkstyle and FindBugs with no trouble.

I did arrive at a partial solution by following the docs at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/running-inspections-offline.html but this requires me to install IntelliJ because Android Studio appears not to include inspect.bat.

Is there and standard gradle support here, the way there is for the other three analysis tools?

Thanks for any help.
NickB

Comment: I have no idea what features intellij static test has, but I think FindBugs and PMD would sufficient for android.

Comment: This plugin ```https://github.com/GradleUp/static-analysis-plugin``` looks as the best solution for automatic static analysis on Android. If you are still interested in this task, it is open for pull requests.